# New to Android: which one to adopt: Eclipse with ADT or Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am new to Android Development. I would request you to gimme some insights on which IDE to use as a newbie and which one is the best pick to stick with as a pro developer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Eclipse for now.http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html. check the caution in the link

Comment: Try them both. Pick the one (or both or neither or something else) that you like best and helps you be the most productive/happy. I personally like Jetbrains products, but they do cost a few pennies when used for commercial development.

Comment: @Md. Khairul Hasan Sujan, approve one of those answer to thank answerers and upvote relevent comments or answers. That's the way it goes on SOF.

Comment: oh I see @Snicolas I have just done this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a beginner point of view you can start with any of these. it will be better if you have some pre knowledge about android development environment tools.  if you are completely new to both Eclipse and android studio and then you should first start with Eclipse .

[Android SDK Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html)

It would be little easy for you to handle otherwise you can start with Android studio.

[Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

Comment: As @Vaibhav Agarwal said, it's really a matter of choice. If you don't want to fall into an IDE religious wars thing, feel really free to choose. Not sure eclipse is gonna be supported still within 2 years though. Personally, I still prefer eclipse, as I find Android Studio is not stable enough yet. But others, and quite good coders, have already switched to it.

Comment: @Snicolas Eclipse will be supported for as long as is relevant .. these things take years to die off xD

Comment: Not sure, Gradle integration is way behind already on eclipse... And if there is one sure thing it's that Gradle is here to stay.

Comment: @Snicolas Sure, it doesn't eliminate the old approaches now - and when it does, those will have been patched over as appropriate. That's one thing with popular tools: for better or worse, they are a freight train. Takes forever to stop them and it's too costly to just derail them (even if it would be better in the long run ;-)

Comment: @user2864740 agree with you these things take years to die off but advance features and IntelliJ IDEA all developers will move to android studio in upcoming years for sure

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal For some people. IntelliJ IDEA (as much as I like Jetbrains and pay for their products) *isn't* Free-As-In-Beer. (Not to mention preferences and tool/ecosystem biases.)

Comment: @user2864740 haha..agree. I rest my case.. ;) but i am sure with lil easy implementation on android studio will force developers to use it...

Answer (score 0):

The android studio is still in the early acccess preview, so its not advisable to start developing with it as a complete fresher. Since most of the developers use eclipse, you will be finding more help in the forums.

Android studio still has many disadvantages.

Once you develope in eclipse, and when the real version of android studio is released you can easily migrate your app to studio with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Well Android Studio has been developed after **Eclipse** and also **it is dedicated to develop android applications only**.

So you might find it really supportive as far as we are talking about Android Application Development.

> Although if you are going to develop some open source applications and
>   just by plugging in some real development plugins then you must go for
>   Eclipse.

And to make it comprehensive enough and to open you with the features let me take you to the

**GOOGLE  IO - 2013**

This RIP will make it clear,

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pmPa_KxsAM